# Unable to convert csv file to text tab delimited file in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion, csv

Instead of manually convert `csv` file to text tab delimited file using excel software

[image]

I would like to automate this process using Python.

However, using the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410395/6446053)

```
with open('endnote_csv.csv', 'r') as fin:
       with open('endnote_deliminated.txt', 'w', newline='') as fout:
           reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=',')
           writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
           writer.writeheader()
           writer.writerows(reader)
```

Return an error of

> ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: None

May I know where did I do wrong,

The `csv` file is accessible via the following [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/155rJ8EaSIXEjc0F0m_ia0ROXL2F2znt2/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: your source file is not a proper .csv file.  It has tons of commas in the middle of the entries.

Comment: this may help out if you want to avoid pandas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Python package called `pandas` to do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
fname = 'endnote_csv'
pd.read_csv(f'{fname}.csv').to_csv(f'{fname}.tsv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Here's how it works:

- `pd.read_csv(fname)` - reads a CSV file and stores it as a `pd.DataFrame` object (not important for this example)
- `.to_csv(fname)` - writes a `pd.DataFrame` to a CSV file given by `fname`
- `sep='\t'` - replaces the `','` used in CSVs with a tab character
- `index=False` - use this to remove the row numbers

If you want to be a bit more advanced and use the command line only, you can do this:

```py
# csv-to-tsv.py
import sys

import pandas as pd

fnames = sys.argv[1:]

for fname in fnames:
    main_name = '.'.join(fname.split('.')[:-1])
    pd.read_csv(f'{main_name}.csv').to_csv(f'{main_name}.tsv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

This will allow you to run a command like this from the command line and change all `.csv` files to `.tsv` files in one go:

```sh
python csv-to-tsv.py *.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this and come back to you.

Comment: Hi, apparently, this save the doc as tsv instead of txt format

Comment: just change everywhere it says `'.tsv'` to `'.txt'` - for example: `pd.read_csv(f'{main_name}.csv').to_csv(f'{main_name}.txt', sep='\t', index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

It is erroring out on comma seperated author names. It appears that columns in the underline rows exceeds number of headers.